# Can I assign multiple datatypes to a Pandas column?

Tags: pandas

I have a huge amount of data any work on this data takes up a really long time. One of the tips that I read to deal with a large amount of data is to change the datatypes of the columns to either 'int' or 'float' if possible.

I tried to follow this method but I am getting some errors because my column contains both float and string values. The error looks like this "Unable to parse string "3U00" at position 18". Hence my question:

1) Is there a way I can assign multiple data types to one column and how can I do that?
2) If I am able to achieve the above does this decrease my processing time?

**Currently when I type :**

```
dftest.info()
```

**Result:**

```
A_column               non-null object
```

Comment: 1. in general no, although you may be able to use  a "category type" if the values repeat a lot. 2. assigning a data type reduces memory usage and allows you to do numerical operations much faster (or at all). It all depends on what you want to do...

Comment: you can't convert alphabets into numerical datatype. If you don't want to keep these records you can pass errors = 'ignore' while converting into numeric. if you want to keep all columns into same data type, you can convert into string...